# Jquery change dialog open to dialog show

Tags: jquery, html

i m using calendar scheduler. when i click on calendar date, dialog opens up for adding new event.

code :

```
$('#add-event-form').dialog('open');
```

but i want a div tag to be shown above calendar and not popup like dialog box.

code i tried

```
$('#add-event-form').show('open');
```

here, open is an another function inside dialog function

```
$("#add-event-form").dialog(
{
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event,ui){//some code}
}
```

any suggestion how i can remove dialog and show div using Jquery show and hide method.

Comment: try modal:false, it will open div inline

Comment: issue is buttons r lost. i think buttons are added dynamically. code : buttons:{cancel : function() {},edit : function(){ } }

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
$("#add-event-form").dialog({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } });
$("#add-event-form").dialog({ hide: "explode" });
```

Comment: $("#add-event-form").dialog({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } }); i replaced this code with $('#add-event-form').dialog('open'); but now neither dialog not div tag is showing